# Symfony Deserialize The type of the key "amount" must be "int" ("string" given)

Tags: php, symfony

Im creating simple rest controller and I want to add create action via POST method. I have entity Product with field $price.

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Price::class)]
private Collection $price;
```

Price entity has field

```
#[ORM\Column]
private int $amount;
```

Im trying to send JSON:

```
{
    "name": "asd",
    "price": {
        "amount": 3
    }
}
```

but when I try to deserialize in my controller function:

```
#[Route('', name: 'products_create', methods: 'POST')]
public function create(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $requestBody = $request->getContent();
    $product = $this->serializer->deserialize($requestBody, Product::class, 'json');
    dd($product);
}
```

I get an error: The type of the key "amount" must be "int" ("string" given).
As you can see In my json I pass field as numeric, not string. How I can deserialize this value properly without turning off type checking?